# How do I make my embedded pdf file to be full screen on my website?

Tags: php, html, css, iframe, fullscreen

This is what I've got but this doesn't solve the problem for different devices and screen sizes.

```html
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="FILE LINK" width="1920" height="1080"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make it full screen? I've tried width: 100%; height: 100%

Answer (score 2):

For reaching fullscreen in this case you need to use `height: 100vh;`, `width: 100%;`

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.landing {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.image-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 6px solid #00f;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-list .image {
  border: 6px solid #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.centered-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 280px;
}
.centered-element ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.centered-element ul span {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<!-- body -->

<section class='landing'>
    
    <ul class='image-list'>
        <li class='image'
                style='background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/1600)'>
        </li>
        <li class='image'
                style='background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/1800)'>
        </li>
        <li class='image'
                style='background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1600/1700)'>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    
</section>

<!-- /body -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple snippet like the following one did the trick for me:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="#" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Just play with the containers.

You should of course set your own container sizes to 100% and not `html` and `body`.